# Regex to match django block templatetag

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm currently writing a quick python script to adapt all my old templates to a new base-template.
To do this I need to move the code inside the {% block body %} somewhere else.

I already got this one to match all my {% load smth %}

```
r"\{% load [^\{%]+? %\}"
```

What I want to match is the code between {% block body %} and {% endblock %}
Example:

```
{% block body %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            [...]
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Unless you don't have nested blocks, you can't do this with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving the obvious problem of nested blocks aside, this would be the regex to match all not-nested blocks:

```
\{% block [^\{%]+? %\}[\s\S]*\{% endblock %\}
```

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, there is no way to use regexp here, unless you use the notation {% endblock body %}, or you don't use nested blocks. Here is an example why it will fail:

```
{% block body %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            {% block foo %}
            [...]
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

regex will catch nested {% endblock %} as end of the body block

Comment: Yeah I know. But I want a quick solution, which would eventually work in 95% of all cases. Although I'm open for a solution (in Python), which involves nested blocks.

Comment: well, I was wrong. With greedy expression nested blocks are not an issue, assuming body's endblock is the last in tempate

Comment: e.g. re.search('{%\sblock\scontainer\s%}(.*){%\sendblock\s%}', template, re.M+re.S) works for me